# How to set a severity of a build if it do not work in certain combination?

Tags: manual-testing

I have a windows application installed on Windows Desktop OS. Another module is server module which is installed on server(Windows server 08,2012). These two modules communicate with each other over a network. I have below scenario which has to be grouped in bug severity. Below are some observations.

**Testing**

- Client installs successfully
- There is no client crash during running.
- Icon do not appear on taskbar[High]

**Machine 1** [Pass]

- Windows 10 <-> Windows server 2008 (Works as expected)
- Windows 10 <-> Windows server 2012 (Works as expected)
- Windows 10 <-> Windows server 2008 with NLA (Works as expected)
- Windows 10 <-> Windows server 2012 with NLA (Works as expected)

**Machine 2** [Pass] (runs on other two windows 8.1 machine)

- Windows 8.1 <-> Windows server 2008 (Works as expected)
- Windows 8.1 <-> Windows server 2012 (Works as expected)
- Windows 8.1 <-> Windows server 2008 with NLA (Works as expected)
- Windows 8.1 <-> Windows server 2012 with NLA (Works as expected)

**Machine 3** [Blocker] (Laptop)

- Windows 8.1 <-> Windows server 2008 (Error 2,3,4)
- Windows 8.1 <-> Windows server 2012 (Error 2,3,4)
- Windows 8.1 <-> Windows server 2008 with NLA (Error 2,3,4)
- Windows 8.1 <-> Windows server 2012 with NLA (Error 1)

**Machine 4** [Pass]

- Windows 7 <-> Windows server 2008 (Works as expected)
- Windows 7 <-> Windows server 2012 (Works as expected)
- Windows 7 <-> Windows server 2008 with NLA (Works as expected)
- Windows 7 <-> Windows server 2012 with NLA (Works as expected)

> Below are error generated on server machine in event viewer

**Error 1.** RDPClient_SSL: An error was encountered when transitioning from TsSslStateHandshakeInProgress to TsSslStateDisconnecting in response to TsSslEventHandshakeContinueFailed

**Error 2.** The certificate received from the remote server was issued by an untrusted certificate authority. Because of this, none of the data contained in the certificate can be validated. The SSL connection request has failed. The attached data contains the server certificate

**Error 3.** A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 48. The Windows SChannel error state is 552.

**Error 4.** An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint 0.0.0.0:38863.  The error status code is contained within the returned data.

> **What should be the result?**
>
> - Should the build be rejected as it is not working on one of the machine ?
> - How to severe it should be to be a blocker issue?
> - Do i have to reject both builds if issue found?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the business owners set the severity? Unless it blocks testing just signal the issue. Same goes for rejecting the build, maybe its fine to release with a known issue list.

I think you should discuss this internally within the company and set standards. Like if errors happen on this or that, then we do this or that. There is not a one-size fits all solution for your questions, greatly depends on the context.

Some observations from my side:

> Icon do not appear on taskbar [High]

- What if no users really use the taskbar-icon? Is it really that high?

> Machine 3 [Blocker] (Laptop)

- Windows 8.1? 7.92% usage statistics, is this really a blocker? Verify if you have users using Windows 8.1.
- Also this looks like an configuration issue on the client-side